# Escape PostgreSQL string values

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, pg-promise

I'm trying to insert over 70k values to my postgres database. However, each rows have different types of special characters. When I insert I get the usual error. for example: 
`syntax error at or near ".5"`. I'm using the module pg-promise. Below the code that I'm using:

```
  function pg_insert(x) {
        var name = x["name"];
        var lastName = x["lasname"];

        var sql = `insert into table(name, lastname)`;
        var values = `values (${name},${lastname})`;

        pg.db
        .none(sql + values)
        .then(data => {})
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is `${name}` string interpolation? If yes, I would suggest to use parametrized query to avoid problems with quoting and possible SQL Injection.

Comment: How would I do that?. Nvm, just found how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lukasz mentions, use a [Parameterized Query](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#parameterized-queries):

```
  function pg_insert(x) {
    const name = x['name'];
    const lastName = x['lasname'];

    const sql = 'insert into table(name, lastname) values ($1, $2)';
    const values = [name, lastname];

    pg.db
    .none(sql, values)
    .then(data => {})
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

You could also use [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#named-parameters):

```
  function pg_insert(x) {
    const sql = 'insert into table(name, lasname) values (${name}, ${lastname})';

    pg.db
    .none(sql, x)
    .then(data => {})
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

However, as mentioned in the [`pg-promise` Named Parameters documentation](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters):

> Keep in mind that while property values null and undefined are both formatted as null, an error is thrown when the property does not exist.

If any of the properties from your passed object `x` are nonexistent *(e.g. `x.name`, `x.lasname`, `{ "name": "Joe" }`(note the missing `lasname` property))*, then the Named Parameters example code above will produce an error.

As vitaly-t (the library creator) mentions, there are [helper methods](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html#.format) in `pg-promise` to assist with missing data. But, if you can not guarantee the shape of the data that will be passed into the query and aren't interested in adding the code necessary to sanitize the data, then a Parameterized Query may be the easier option for failure-proofing.

It's left to the reader to determine which method make the most sense for their use-case.

Comment: The suggestion for `Parameterized Queries` may be misplaced. Library `pg-promise` itself provides several ways to deal with missing values and defaults for them, from the base method `as.format`, which takes such options, to the `helpers` namespace that also works with such defaults. Anyhow, `Parameterzied Queries` wouldn't be a good alternative here.

Answer (score 2):

If you just use [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters) correctly, then it will work:

```
function pg_insert(x) {
    pg.db.none('INSERT INTO table(name, lastname) VALUES(${name}, ${lastname})', x)
    .then(data => {})
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have also amended the [official documentation](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters) to include the following:

> **WARNING:** Never use `${}` syntax inside ES6 template strings, as those have no knowledge of how to format values for PostgreSQL. Inside ES6 template strings you can only use one of the 4 alternatives - `$()`, `$<>`, `$[]` or `$//`.

...to make it more clear.